# Bundler install custom path issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

`gem env` shows

```
GEM PATHS:

  /usr/local/share/gems
```

I would like to use `bundle install --deployment --path=/usr/local/share/gems` to install my bundled gems.

The problem is that the bundle install creates a folder **ruby** and puts the **gems** folder inside the **ruby** folder.

When this happens my ruby code is unable to find the gems in its default path.

Looks like I am missing some configuration parameter. Help please.

Comment: Are you using the `bundle` command to load your code? You can't use `--path` and just ignore bundler.

Comment: I am using `ruby` command to run the code. I am not sure what you are referencing `--path` with bundler.

Comment: You can't use `ruby`, you have to use `bundle exec ruby path-to-your.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Maurício Linhares comments in the question has resolved the issue.

When using bundler to install gems use bundle exec ruby. When the `bundle install --deployment` happens the path information goes into .bundle/config

```
bundle exec ruby path-to-ruby-script.rb
```

The above execution Will find the gems installed by the `bundle` command.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to force installation to the system gem location, I believe `bundle install --deployment --system` will do what you want.